# SQL Repetition, how to avoid in query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm trying to get the names and the addresses that are stored in the table but getting data repetition. I dont know how to avoid it as im a newbie to this field. here's some pictures of the commands and results.

Commands:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Owner Table:

[image]

Addresses Table:

[image]

Please help me out :(

P.S. They are all dummy data.

Comment: You will need to `Join` the two tables on some key.  What other identifying columns exist in those tables that you can `Join` on?  Does your Addresses table have an ID of which Owner it belongs to?

Comment: is there any relation exist between Owners and Addresses?

Comment: Learn how to use `join`.  If you don't know what that is, then you need to learn the basics of relational databases.

Comment: Lemme upload the tables here...

Comment: So its ownerID that links the tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a join between the two tables owners and addresses using column in tables that referenece each other.

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,addressline_1
FROM owners o
JOIN addresses a
ON o.colName=a.colName
```

Your query is performing **cartesian product** between the two tables which is giving all rows for table **address** for each row in table **owners**.

You would have avoided getting meaningless rows had you used recommended  ANSI SQL syntax of performing join using **ON** clause rather than **WHERE** clause . Although you haven't specified condition for joining between the tables still old syntax of joining using **WHERE** clause got executed successfully but would have thrown error in case of using **ON** clause.

[**See this thread for detailed discussion ON vs WHERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

**EDIT**

As per your schema of tables the query would be

```
SELECT firstname,lastname,addressline_1
FROM owners o
JOIN addresses a
ON o.ownerid=a.owners_ownerid
```

Comment: @m hasan.. wow works!! can you explain these `highlighted` bit to me please?


SELECT firstname,lastname,addressline_1
FROM owners `o`
JOIN addresses `a`
ON `o.ownerid=a.owners_ownerid`

Comment: you mean ON/WHERE part..plz click on the link..more detailed answers there

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `where` clause to your query:-

```
SELECT OWNERS.first_name, OWNERS.last_name, ADDRESSES.address_line1
FROM OWNERS, ADDRESSES
WHERE OWNERS.ownerid = ADDRESSES.owners_ownerid
```

or you can use `join`

```
SELECT OWNERS.first_name, OWNERS.last_name, ADDRESSES.address_line1
FROM OWNERS
JOIN ADDRESSES
ON OWNERS.ownerid = ADDRESSES.owners_ownerid
```

Comment: Thanks @Sampat check the updated tables... I'll try your sql and let you know :)